# Running Android Studio behind a corporate proxy: Unable to resolve dependency

Tags: maven, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I’m running Android Studio 3.3 installed on a company system, connected to the company’s proxy. Whenever I try to execute `Make Project`, I get the following errors:

`ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02.`

`ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc02.`

I've tried the following:

- Set Hostname (xx.x.x.xxx), Port (8080), Login and Password in `Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > HTTP Proxy` and checked `Proxy authentication`.

  - My password contains a special character ($), I've written it without any change.
  - When I click on `Check Connection` and enter http://www.google.com, it shows me this error: `Problem with connection: Connection reset`. I'm able to access this URL after entering proxy credentials in my browser (Google Chrome).
- Modified my `build.gradle` as shown below to resolve repository errors. Also checked `Enable embedded Maven repository` under `Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle > Android Studio`.
- Added the top level certificate to Android Embedded JRE's `cacerts` file using KeyStore Explorer. I'm using the embedded JDK bundled with Android Studio.
- Added proxy settings to `gradle-wrapper.properties` file as shown below.

I also tried to run an http request code on `IntelliJ IDEA Community 2018.3.3`, configuring the same proxy settings. The code runs with no errors in my personal computer (on open network) but gives me a `Connection timed out: connect` error when I run the same code on the company system (connected to proxy).

This might indicate the problem originates from IntelliJ, since Android Studio is based on it. Switching to open network on the company system is not an option.

**Note**: I can access [Google's Maven Repository](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html) from the browser so I don't think the proxy is blocking the URL.

Related issue on jetbrains: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-153423
How can I solve the dependency errors on the company system's Android Studio?

Relevant code from my main `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com"}
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com"}
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Relevant code from my app `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc02'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Relevant code from my app `gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```js
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip

systemProp.proxySet="true"
systemProp.http.keepAlive="true"
systemProp.http.proxyHost=<xx.x.x.xxx>
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=<username>
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=<password, has $ character in it>

systemProp.https.keepAlive="true"
systemProp.https.proxyHost=<xx.x.x.xxx>
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyUser=<username>
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=<password, has $ character in it>
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue of my @# corporate proxy policy. Could you please let me know did you solve that issue if yes please share the way you worked on.